# Entity relation criteria in Doctrine2

Tags: database, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I have the AdminFiles entity which holds files for all project entities (news, pages, events etc.). It is structured (abridged) like this:

```
id          int(11) Auto Increment   
entity      varchar(255) // this holds the entity name, e.g. Page or News
entity_id   int(11) NULL // this holds the entity ID
filename    varchar(1000) // this holds the path to the file
```

I would love to access the files in the entities (Page, News etc.) with something like $entity->getFiles(). But I'm having trouble creating the relation, since it is not only constrained by the ID, but also the entity name. Is there any way to join this inside the Doctrine2 entity, or do I have to do this in the service?

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled by Doctrine by using [discriminator map](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_discriminatormap) feature. In your case there will be multiple entities inherited from base `AdminFiles` entity, each one will be specific for single type of files (e.g. `PageFiles`, `NewsFiles` and so on). You will need to establish mapping between `entity` column and these entities into `@DiscriminatorMap` annotation, then you will be able to fetch just one particular type of file by fetching (or using in association mapping) entity that represents some specific type of file.

You will also be able to even have entity properties that are specific to some particular type of file by using this feature.